# unfocus doesn't work when split widget to another file

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I have main.dart

```
part 'home_page.dart';
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String _judul = 'Private Chat';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
      },
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: _judul,
        home: HomePage(), // Using separated file
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And home_page.dart

```
part of 'main.dart';
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: TextField(),
    );
  }
}
```

`FocusScope.of(context).unfocus()` doesn't work when I split widget from main.dart to another file (in this case home_page.dart) so the project will neat.

However It's work when I directly put `HomePage() return` (Scaffold) to main.dart, (I say work because android keybord disappear when unfocused from textfield)

```
part 'home_page.dart';
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String _judul = 'Private Chat';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
      },
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: _judul,
        home: Scaffold(...), //Directly put textfield
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I sus this is context mistake, I have no idea with context properties and method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `GestureDetector` under `MaterialApp` (swap them) and wrap it with `Builder`, like this:

```
 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String _judul = 'Private Chat';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _judul,
      home: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
            },
            child: HomePage(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The reason this is working is because `Builder` gives you new context which is used in `onTap` function of your `GestureDetector`. This new context contains more specific details about position in the widget tree than the one you were previously using (which comes from the build method parameter).

Comment: Thank you It's worked, I'm wonder if It's work with nested widget too. Should i create builder everytime. What i mean with nested widget is, 
```part of 'main.dart';
class CustomInput extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red));
  }
}```

And then at home_page.dart call that CustomInput

Comment: I think in most cases you should be good without using `Builder`. The case in your post was quite specific cause it affected the very beginning of your application, So the `BuildContext` obtained from `MyApp` build method was "too poor" - it didn't have any widgets above. Also, the `GestureDetector` widget was above `MaterialApp`. It's probably better if `MaterialApp` doesn't have any UI related widgets above as `MaterialApp` is kinda the beginning of the UI part of your app